# Vertical-align doesn't work for React Icons in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This topic has been raised many times in this forum and also often causes problems. This time me.I put react icons in my react application project. I'm having trouble positioning icons in the same line with text. It's about the "approved" icons shown in the image below. How can I refine my code so that the icons are in line with the text?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried the following solutions for the above situation:

```
display: flexbox;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
```

then

```
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
```

MY CODE:

```
const templates= ['Instagram templates & styling $500 USD', 'Business/Loyalty Cards $100USD', 'Brand & Website Audit $300USD', 'Additional Web Pages $300', 'Service Menu/Flyer $200 USD', 'Packiging design from $600', 'Price of website + online shop setup - $ 700 USD (up to 15 products)', '+ SEO styler - $ 300 (implement basic SEO to any existing squarespace site)'];

const fourth = templates.map((templates, idx) => {
    return <li key={idx}><TiTickOutline color="#9E7F61" />{templates}</li>
});


<div className="results">
    <div className="service-list">
        <h2 className="results">The kind of result you can expect</h2>
           <ul className="values">
              <li className="positions">{fourth}</li>
           </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.results {
  margin-top: 4em;
}

.results li {
  font-family: 'aperculight', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.positions {
  font-family: 'blacker_displaylight';
  font-size: 50vw;
}

.values {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `display: flexbox` is not a thing in css.

You have to set `display: flex` and that would work.
And also if you have to align it vertically center use `align-items: center` instead of `align-content: center` Like this:

```css
ul {
  display: flex
  align-items: center
}
```

Comment: The CSS bug only appeared here. In the code it looked like display: flex. Despite your hint it didn't work. But I managed to match the icons to the text by choosing the right size of them. Now they are in the same line.